# Latex: how to break the line in multirow inside the tabular

Tags: latex, tabular, multirow

I cannot find out how to break the line inside the multirow in tabular. In my table, a cell should be two rows wide and should have a linebreak to keep the text overlapping the other cells'.

Any suggestions?

Sample of code:

```
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{|p{1cm}|p{2.5cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|}
    \hline
    \multirow{2}{*}{Long text to break} % HERE IS A PROBLEM
        & Thing  & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Thing 2} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Thing 3}    
    \\ \cline{2-6}
        & sth 1 & sth 1 & sth 2 & sth 1  & sth 2 \\ \hline
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could try to `minipage` it:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
    \hline
    \multirow{2}{*}{\begin{minipage}{0.5in}Long text to break\end{minipage}}
    & Thing  & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Thing 2} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Thing 3} \\
    \cline{2-6}
    & sth 1 & sth 1 & sth 2 & sth 1  & sth 2 \\ 
    \hline
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

---

However, in your particular case, my suggestion would simply be to loosen the restrictions of the other columns, because there is too much space wasted there. With each `p{}`, that forces the other columns to be a certain width, so there is not enough room for the first column.

The following code looked presentable to me when I compiled it:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
    \hline
    \multirow{2}{*}{Long text to break}
    & Thing  & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Thing 2} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Thing 3} \\
    \cline{2-6}
    & sth 1 & sth 1 & sth 2 & sth 1  & sth 2 \\
    \hline
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

Comment: I cannot just use "l" parameter in tabular command, because the cell was to width, but the "\begin{minipage}{2cm}Long text to break\end{minipage}" helped me out, thank you.

Answer (score 44):

`p` column and `\parbox` also works:

```
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|p{1.5cm}|l|l|l|l|l|}
    \hline
    \multirow{2}{*}{\parbox{1.5cm}{Long text to break}}
    & Thing  & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Thing 2} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Thing 3} \\
    \cline{2-6}
    & sth 1 & sth 1 & sth 2 & sth 1  & sth 2 \\ 
    \hline
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image: parbox in latex document]

Comment: Thanks, works nice for me. However, I think you should use `\parbox` instead of the TeX `\vbox`

Comment: Thanks! I've updated the answer. Parbox handles space above the text.

Comment: Hello, is there any chance that we can "centering" the "to break" sentence instead of aligned to left?

Comment: @lllllllllllll just add `\centering` into `parbox` contents, e.g.: `{\centering Long text to break}`

Answer (score 16):

for me the **shortest and most practical** answer:

use `\linewidth` as the length for the `{width}` parameter.

```
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|p{1cm}|p{2.5cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|}
\hline
\multirow{2}{\linewidth}{Long text to break} % HERE IS A PROBLEM
    & Thing  & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Thing 2} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Thing 3}    
\\ \cline{2-6}
    & sth 1 & sth 1 & sth 2 & sth 1  & sth 2 \\ \hline
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

**That's it!**

The only possible problem is that in the improbable case that the text in the other cells is really short it may look like that:
[image: Broken text in the right width but sadly going out of the table]

However if typically your table has more text on the other cells than just "sth1" it will look great:
[image]

Comment: How do i prevent the overflow in the multirow column?

Comment: @Midiparse I am sorry I am not able to give you an answer. One possibility might be to put your text in a box and use this box in the multirow environment [just guessing (!)]

Answer (score 7):

For me it worked to use the build-in command of "multirow" -
the {*} is "{width}"

Answer (score 1):

Also, using `parbox` and `\\`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{|p{1cm}|p{2.5cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|}
        \hline
        \multirow{2}{*}{\parbox{1cm}{Long\\ text\\ to\\ break}} % NOT A PROBLEM?
        & Thing  & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Thing 2} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Thing 3}    
        \\ \cline{2-6}
        & sth 1 & sth 1 & sth 2 & sth 1  & sth 2 \\ \hline
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Be anyway careful not to exceed the margins of your cells.